# How do I import `.astro` files in Astro config?

Tags: astrojs

I´m trying to import an Astro component in my astro.config.ts. Starting the dev server fails because vite can not analyse the file.

> Failed to parse source for import analysis because the content contains invalid JS syntax. If you are using JSX, make sure to name the file with the .jsx or .tsx extension.

Comment: I do not think importing a .astro in config is an expected usage, can you detail a bit more on the end goal why importing .astro in the config ?

Answer (score 0):

The `.astro` files cannot work unless they are transformed into javascript files that can be executed by NodeJS.

When you use `astro build` in an Astro project, the build pipeline will be called. Inside the pipeline, Astro *first* tries to parse the config file, and merges its default config with the config provided by users. You can imagine this is done by importing the Astro config file `astro.config.mjs`. *Then*, based on the parsed config file, Astro starts to build your project. Only at this stage `.astro` files get transformed into `.ts` files, and then they are usable.
Therefore, you cannot import `.astro` files inside the `astro.config.mjs` file as `.astro` files are processed only after the handling of `astro.config.mjs`.

I guess you may need some of the exported utility functions in `.astro` files. If this is the case, you can rewrite those utility functions in `astro.config.mjs`, or place them in a separate utility file, e.g. `utils.js`, and you will be able to import them in `astro.config.mjs`.